# My jpg and png image is not showing on my browser?

Tags: html, image, png, jpeg

So I have a logo that I want to show in my browser in HTML, I have tried it as a jpg and a png, neither work. Her is my code:

```
    <html>
  <body>

    <head>
    <title>astro blog pro</title>
    </head>

    <img src="Astro Blog Pro Logo.png" />

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't have to choose the format, you have to put the exact name with the exact format. So go and check it

Comment: ok i changed it still not working

Comment: so, you have this html page in a folder, is the image in the same folder?

Comment: what? Sorry I am really new to html

Comment: It wasn't an html question, just did you put the file in the same folder!

Comment: as @RegEdit the point is, you have this code in a file like `something.html`, which is in a folder... now, is this `Astro Blog Pro Logo.png` in the same folder of the html file?

Comment: I would avoid having spaces in a file name. And check the file permissions

Comment: The value you have in  `src` looks weird (spaces, uppercase folders, ...). It should be the path to the image you want to use, something similar to `src="images/subfolder/logo.png"`. Check where your image is and use that path. This is basic HTML that you should find pretty easily if you search about HTML IMG tag. Good luck!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must add the alt attribute to the img tag. In order for the picture to work properly, it must have an alternative image or name to display if it can't find the src image.

Like so:

```
<img src="img.png" alt="This is my image" />
```

When using the alt attribute, you can name it whatever you want. As alt stands for alternative.

Another reason it might not work:
The image might not be in the same folder as your HTML document. You should move all of your documents into the same folder.

If you are using an online IDE, then there is no solution as you can only use online images with a URL.

Comment: The alt attribute is for an alternative text to show in case the file can't be displayed

Comment: Read the 1st paragraph

Comment: No problem! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

First: You have a `<head>` tag inside your `<body>` tag which is invaild (in all HTML standards). You should read about basics of html document structure.

You can check your syntax e.g. here https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html (there are lot's of syntax checker, also for commandline if you use (Linux)).

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >    
    <title>astro blog pro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="Astro_Blog_Pro_Logo.png" alt="put image description here"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

and btw: do **not use spaces** as `<img>` is a ressource which will be resolved by the browser and spaces map to **%20**, so that "Astro Blog" becomes  "Astro%20Blog"

see: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP